# Why are OS's referred to 64-bit instead of 8-byte?

Tags: architecture, operating-system

Why are operating systems referred to as 64-bit and 32-bit instead of 8-byte and 4-byte? Wouldn't it be easier once OS's get that high?

Comment: From the days far back when memory was expensive up to be a limiting factor,  in a time where TTL was best practice and CMOS expensive and prone to damage by static electricity, every *bit* was something precious, even more so within the CPU. Another thing is that 64 (blur the unit) advertises better than 8.

Comment: The number of bytes isn't interesting by itself. What's interesting is the number of bits, which directly determines both the address space and the value range of integers.

Answer (score 0):

This is more to do with the era in which those architectures were created - [the 1980's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86). At the time the fastest thing was significantly slower than your smart phone right now, why would you call it 4 byte, when it is almost unrealistic to expect a 16 byte computer in your life time.

It would have been called the 4 byte chipset if the next version was likely to be the 8 byte, a year or two later, followed by the 16 byte shortly after that - as it was, engineers did not foresee the incredibly fast growth of the microchip, and thus the computer - so why name something after the non-base unit (bits, not bytes)

It is a similar reason to why are (have) run out of IPV4 addresses, because the group that created them (interestingly enough, IPv4 addresses are 32 bits long) did not believe there would be a need for any more than that in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

The reason processors are referred two in terms of bits rather than bytes is because many processors do not us an integral number of bytes.

Sperry 1100 and DEC-10/DEC-20 systems used 36-bits. There were 12-bit CPUs commonly used for word processors at one time.

It's easier to compare in bits than bytes.